# npm run build - Failed to compile - Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

When using `npm run build` in my react app (create-react-app), 
it fails to compile and gives me the message `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`.

I am not using `toLowerCase` in my app and figured the only place where this is used is in the script : `node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js` in this piece of code:

```
if (
  process.env.CI &&
  (typeof process.env.CI !== 'string' ||
    process.env.CI.toLowerCase() !== 'false') &&
  messages.warnings.length
) {
  console.log(
    chalk.yellow(
      '\nTreating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.\n' +
      'Most CI servers set it automatically.\n'
    )
  );
  return reject(new Error(messages.warnings.join('\n\n')));
}
```

What seems strange to me is that even there, it should not even give me `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` because if `processe.env.CI` was undefined it should read the first conditional statement as false-y and not even read  `processe.env.CI.toLowerCase`. 
Also I have tried deleting this whole section of code and I get the same error. 
I have another react-app and the `npm run build` command works just fine, so I am really at loss wondering where I should even look for the answer.

Comment: Interesting. I this the only occurrence of `toLowerCase` in your entire project?

Comment: Yes it is! 
What is strange too is that I have not change this build.js file as it is built with create-react-app. And I have used it other times before, when deploying my app and there was never an issue with it

Answer (score 6):

Ok, 
this is very weird but here is what my problem was:

```
.collage{
margin: ;
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: stretch;}
```

I had a typo for my margin value, and this simple bug was what was blocking the wole thing and giving me a `toLowerCase` issue!!!!

I would have never guessed !

Comment: How did you find that bug; did you see anything in the logs or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because of "**important**" at border-width:

```
&.checkbox-accent {
    > span {
        border-width: get($checkbox-config, types, accent, borderWidth) !important;
        border-style: solid !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;

        &:after {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

In my case error message was:

```
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector .checkbox.checkbox-accent>span
```

so i was able to find an exact file & row

Comment: What exactly was your fix then?

Comment: I've removed "!important", and that's it.
Fortunately it wasn't actually nessecary in that place.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue cause with `!important` being used where variable where `undefined`:

```
    .form-checkbox,
    .form-radio {

        input {

            &:checked {
                background-color: color-bg(check-checked-inverse) !important;
                border-color: color-bg(check-checked-inverse) !important;
            }
        }
    }
```

It could be fixed with :

```
    .form-checkbox,
    .form-radio {

        input {

            &:checked {
                background-color: color-bg(check-checked-inverse);
                border-color: color-bg(check-checked-inverse);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or by settings the variable `check-checked-inverse`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not using toLowerCase in my app

Well you clearly are when calling build.js.

Either way, in an if() statement, each individual statement will be tested. It won't "break out" if say the first fails.
As you have not set the environment property 'CI' then this if statement will always fails as process.env.CI will always be undefined/null.
.toLowerCase() is a method that will NOT work on nulls.

Comment: Yes, it will "break out" if the first one fails. If `CI` is not set, `process.env.CI` will be `undefined`, and the other ones will not be checked.

Comment: Fair enough.
Maybe it is me being more used to Java. Sorry.