# npm run build error - Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I try to build my react application, the following error appears:

```
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector .btn-white
```

I have looked at the forum answers to the questions and tried to delete all the css classes with the name `btn-white` without success, even after running `npm clear`, still the same error. I have multiple CSS files, in modules and in my app, I can't delete each file one by one.

Here are all the css elements that use the btn-white (elements in the node_modules not included) :

```
// buttons
    .btn {
      span {
        color: $white;
      }
      &.btn-white {
        span {
          color: $black;
        }
      }
      &.btn-icon {
        i {
          color: $white;
        }
      }
      &.btn-dark,
      &.btn-outline-dark,
      &.btn-flat-dark {
        color: $gray-600;
      }
      &.btn-dark {
        background-color: $gray-700 !important;
      }
      &.btn-outline-dark {
        border-color: $gray-700;
        color: $gray-600;
      }
      &.btn-flat-dark {
        &:active,
        &:focus {
          background: $gray-700;
        }
      }
      &.btn-white {
        color: $body-color;
      }
    }

// other file
  &.btn-white {
    color: $body-color;
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active {
      color: $body-color !important;
    }
  }

// for white button (other file)
.btn.btn-white ~ .dropdown-menu {
  .dropdown-item:not(.acitve):hover {
    color: $body-color !important;
  }
  .dropdown-item.active {
    color: $body-color;
  }
}
```

How to solve this problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where have you used `toLowerCase()` function? Can search in your repo? You are trying to do toLowerCase of an undefined variable

Comment: Not related to this error, here is a quote of the same problem: "I had a typo for my margin value, and this simple bug was what was blocking the wole thing and giving me a toLowerCase issue!" No way to locate the error more precisely? (like a line or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find the problem. I had to go back to the imports, it took me more than 3 hours. The problem came from the class: `.btn-#{$color_name}.btn-#{$color_type}` (complicated to find) and delete all `!important`.
I hope you will never have the same problem :)

Comment: By the way, do you have an explanation of why removing `!important` make it work?

Comment: Might be because `!important` is being used where variable were `undefined`, and thus build fail.

Answer (score 0):

maybe look through all your CSS files for "btn-white", it seems like a lot of people get this error if they got some sort of wrong CSS.
[Same Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212280/npm-run-build-failed-to-compile-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefi)

Or could you add your CSS File were the name "btn-white" accures?

Comment: Could you try to remove all the "!important"? Maybe the color vars aren't set correctly?